# Check $scope variable with jasmine return error

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, angular-mock

Currently trying to check very simple angular variables and functions. I cannot get even the simplest to work. This is my first time using it, and I need to use the older version as my lecturer requires it.

In the app.js I have many controllers but im only starting with one controller, with one variable assigned to a string:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);
blah blah blah etc etc

app.controller('HomeController', function ($scope) {
 $scope.name = 'Batman';
}
```

In the runner.html file I have the following:

```
<script src="lib/jasmine-2.2.0/jasmine.js"></script>
<script src="lib/jasmine-2.2.0/jasmine-html.js"></script>
<script src="lib/jasmine-2.2.0/boot.js"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src='https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular-mocks.js'></script>

<!-- include source files here... -->
<script src="../js/main.js"></script>

<!-- include spec files here... -->
<script src="spec/test.js"></script>
```

In the test.js i have the following:

```
describe('myApp', function () {
  var scope, controller;

  beforeEach(angular.mock.module('myApp'));

  beforeEach(angular.mock.inject(function($controller,$rootScope){
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    $controller('HomeController', {$scope: scope});
  }));

  it('sets the name', function () {
    expect(scope.name).toBe('Batman');
  });
});
```

I then get the following error when I run the test:
Error: [$injector:modulerr]

**EDIT**

It appears to be the angular routing causing the problem. When I removed the route module 'ngRoute' it appears to function correctly. Is there is method to using jasmine with routing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with this was you were not having `angular-route` library included despite having it as a module dependency (`angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute'])`).

I added as the following along with other libraries:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular-route.min.js"></script>
```

And it's working!

Here's [**working plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/0WHHkV87cnCqINMtPvVQ?p=preview)